# Smallest odd $n$ for which there exists a proper linear cyclic code of dimension $5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Find the smallest odd value of $n$ for which there is a proper linear cyclic code of length $n$ and dimension $k = 5$.

For a proper code, $k < n$. So $n \geq 7$. My notes say we need a proper factor of degree $d = n-k$ of $1+x^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

I've been given the irreducible polynomials:

$1+x^7 = (1+x)(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^3)$

$1+x^9 = (1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x^3+x^6)$

$1+x^{11} = (1+x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{10})$

$1+x^{13} = (1+x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{12})$

$1+x^{15} = (1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^4)(1+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3x^4)$

I don't understand why $1+x^{15}$ "has a proper factor" of degree $10$ but the others don't have factors of their respective degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n$ odd, any $x^n+1$ can be factored as $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-\alpha^i)$ where $\alpha$ is an element of multiplicative
order $n$ in an *extension* field of the binary field $\mathbb F_2$.
Unfortunately, choosing $k$ factors from these $n$ 
factors *arbitrarily* does not result in a polynomial with
*binary* coefficients
and so one cannot use such a polynomial as the (parity-check)
polynomial of a *binary* cyclic code. We need to find a 
*binary* polynomial divisor of $x^n+1$, and such binary polynomials
$h(x)$ have the property that if $h(\alpha^i)=0$, then $h(\alpha^{2i})$
also equals $0$. $h^{2i}$ is called a *conjugate* of $\alpha^i$.
This is similar to the more familiar fact that if $f(x)$,
a polynomial with *real* coefficients has a *complex* root $z$,
then $z^*$, the *conjugate* of $z$ is also a root of $f(x)$.
In finite fields, an element can have *many* conjugates, not just
one as in the complex field.

For your specific question, you are *given* the factorization
of $x^n+1$ into *binary* polynomials for $n=7,9,11,13,15$.
To construct a binary cyclic code of dimension $5$, pick some
*subset* of these factors whose degrees add up to $5$ and use
this as the parity-check polynomial of your binary cyclic code
of dimension $5$. A quick look shows that you can't find polynomials
whose degrees add up to $5$ for $n=7,9,11,13$, but you *can* find
such a set when $n=15$ (e.g. $x^4+x+1$ and $x+1$, can you find another?),
and you are done.

Comment: Oh right. I didn't realise they failed because you couldn't find such a subset thankyou. Now I see $1+x^15$ also has $x^4+x^3+x$ and $x+1$